# Javascript Data Manipulation Inefficiency

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have data in the form of `Array[Object{state: "New York", date: 2019-01-02, id: "12297"}, Object{state: "California", date: 2019-01-03, id: "1000"}...]` and I am trying to remove all duplicates by `id` from the data set.

Currently I am using the following, which works, but is awfully inefficient and crawls:

```
uniques = Array.from(new Set(data.map(a => a.ID)))
  .map(ID => {
   return data.find(a => a.ID === ID)});
```

The above gives me data in the same format as the above`[Object{} Object{}...]`

I can also remove all duplicates by doing the following:

```
uniques = d3.rollup(data,
          function(group) {
            const IDs = group.map(g => g.ID);
            const uniqueIDs = new Set(IDs);
            return uniqueIDs.size;
          },
          // first group by cuisine type
          function(d) { return d.state; },
          function(d) { return d.date; },
          function(d) { return d.ID})
```

But I have no idea how to break the data down to the same object format that I had above.  I am essentially trying to end up with a count of inspections by month by state, which if I have the data in the above mentioned format I can do the following:

```
inspectionsByMonth = {
  const counts = d3.rollup(uniques,
        inspections => d3.count(inspections, i => i.ID),
        d => d3.timeMonth(d.date).getTime(),
        d => d.state);

  return Array.from(counts, (([date, map]) => {
    map.set('total', d3.sum(map.values()));
    map.set('month', new Date(date));
    return Object.fromEntries(map)
  })); 
}
```

Can someone help me either A) Get the data to a format that allows me to use my inspectionsByMonth function or B) Explain how I can fix inspectionsByMonth function to handle the new data format?  I have been banging my head against this for a while and am at a loss.  Brand new to JS.

**UPDATE**

I have now tried the following:

```
const dataArray = [new Set(data.map(a => a.inspectionID))]
uniques = dataArray.map(ID => {return data.find(a => a.ID === ID)});
```

This returns `undefined`

Comment: instead of a `Set`, why don't you use a `Map`? `[...new Map(data.map(item => [item.id, item])).values()]`

Comment: @Thomas Throws the error "TypeError: Iterator value 12297 is not an entry object" if I change Array.from(new Set(data.map).... to Array.from(new Map(data.map)...

Comment: const arr2 = [... new Set(arr)];
console.log(arr2);
Try this and then work on returned array

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather I don't understand i'm sorry

Comment: ES6 spread operator quite easily converts Set to an Array Type. So you do not need to use Array.from() initially

Comment: Simply use  const dataArray =   [... new Set(data)] ;    to get your array to use map() method for further processing.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Added update above.  Receiving undefined now with this method.  What am I missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211153/discussion-between-stormsedge-and-imran-rafiq-rather).

Answer (score 0):

1.Here is the solution to remove the duplicates from the array based on the ids.

```js
const data = [
{state: "New York", date: 2019-01-02, id: "12297"},
{state: "California", date: 2019-01-03, id: "1000"},
{state: "New York", date: 2019-01-02, id: "12297"},
{state: "California", date: 2019-01-03, id: "1000"},
];

const idsArray = data.map(obj=>obj.id);
console.log(idsArray);

const uniqueIds = [... new Set(idsArray)];
console.log(uniqueIds);

const filteredData = data.filter((obj,index)=>{
  return obj.id == uniqueIds[index];
})

console.log(filteredData);
```

Hope this will be of some help to you :)